# How do I parse JSON requests in my Play project

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am building a simple web server with Scala + Play.  I am having trouble figuring out how to accept and deserialize JSON requests into objects of my predefined types.  I need help 1) downloading a well-supported JSON package, 2) importing the package in my code to parse the HTTP requests, and 3) actually parsing some JSON.

Here is what I am putting in my SBT file for #1:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.2.9"
```

Here's how I'm trying to import it for #2:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
```

Here's where I try to parse some JSON in my action:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

object Application extends Controller {
  case class Credentials(username: String, password: String)

  def login = Action { request =>
      Ok(Json.obj("message" -> "You tried to log in as: " + parse(request.body).extract[Credentials].username))
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  I am getting an error at runtime which says: "play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[controllers.Application.parse.type does not take parameters]"

Comment: do you really need jerkson? consider using play-json or json4s: https://github.com/json4s/json4s instead, which are easier to integrate with Scala.

Comment: I guess I wasn't sure which was the best one to use.  I'm going to try json4s.  I added it to my SBT file with `libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.2.9"`.  When I build, it successfully downloads the packages but for some reason I am getting an error on my import line `import org.json4s._` that says "cannot resolve the symbol 'json4s'".  Do you have any idea what the issue is?

Comment: I tried compiling and it seems like the imports are actually OK (IntelliJ complains, but I guess they do actually work).  The issue now is that I am getting this error at runtime: "play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[controllers.Application.parse.type does not take parameters]"

Comment: RTFM: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonHttp

Comment: We use play.api.libs.json and it is working ok, you can have automatic serialization, using implicit val .. [Class]; formatters and you can make your own formatter (If you want to parse the json and building custom object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're suffering from namespace pollution. Your `Application` controller inherits a `parse` object from the `play.api.mvc.Controller` trait, and `import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._` includes its own `parse` in the namespace. I'm surprised this even compiles. Making it more explicit will work. Drop the wildcard from the import, and explicitly call `JsonMethods.parse`.

As the commments suggest, this is all really unnecessary. Play's built in json libraries work pretty well, so I also suggest you read up on them and use them. There are plenty of other SO posts related to Play JSON as well.

Comment: Play's built in APIs seem unnecessarily complicated.  Why would I want to define Writes/Reads for every type I want to serialize/deserialize?  Sorry if I am totally missing something.  Isn't it a lot less boiler plate code if I use a framework like json4s?

Comment: `implicit val jsonFormat: Format[Credentials] = Json.format[Credentials]` is minimal boilerplate for defining reads/writes for a case class. Play also aggregates validation errors and leaves you the option of making your validation rules more complication if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I've up-voted your answer and comment.  It still seems to me like json4s has zero boilerplate.  Is there another drawback I'm missing?

Comment: I can't really attest to how good or bad json4s is, as I have everything I've needed so far from Play's built-in json libraries. There's also plenty of documentation and support. But if json4s suits your needs, then by all means use it.